# confluent-kafka-python library: read offset per topic per consumer_group

Tags: pykafka, confluent-kafka-python

Due to [pykafka EOL](https://github.com/Parsely/pykafka/issues/944) we are in the process of migration to [confluent-kafka-python](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python). For `pykafka` we wrote an elaborated script that produced output in the format:

| topic | consumer group | offset |
| --- | --- | --- |
| topic_alpha | total_messages | 100 |
| topic_alpha | consumer_a | 10 |
| topic_alpha | consumer_b | 25 |

I am wondering whether there is a Python code that knows how to do something similar for the `confluent-kafka-python`?

*small print*: there is a partial example on how to [read offsets per given consumer_group](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/list_offsets.py). However, I struggle to get the list of `consumer_group` per topic without manually parsing `__consumer_offsets`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `admin_client.list_groups()` to get a list of groups, and `admin_client.list_topics()` to get all topics and partitions in the cluster and `client.get_watermark_offsets()` for the given topics.

Then for each consumer group instantiate a new consumer with the corresponding `group.id`, create a TopicPartition list to query committed offsets for and then call `c.committed()` to retrieve the committed offsets.
Subtract the committed offsets from the high watermark to get th